# OpenJDK 9 SSL error with gradlew

Tags: ssl, java, gradlew

I recently upgraded to OpenJDK 9 but am now encountering errors with CI build.

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors
>   parameter must be non-empty

I tried to symlinking

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts
>
> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

But did not work, can confirm Slim version works but i'd rather not use this. Is there any quick hack or work around to use until the issue is resolved down the line?

Comment: it could be a permissions problem, try adding this system property at the startup : -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts